# Qt : Qlabel and QPushButton in a QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have an issue, when I'm trying to add a QLabel and a QPushbutton object into a QVBoxLayout. The problem is, that it adds too much space between them like in the picture

[image: Sample]

Here is a code example of creating the layouts and the labels, and adding them. I'm adding the buttons later on, but that is just with another ->addWidget(button).

```
jobbcimke= new QLabel(trUtf8("Jobb oldal"));
jobbkozepcimke= new QLabel(trUtf8("Jobb part"));
balcimke= new QLabel(trUtf8("Bal oldal"));
balkozepcimke=new QLabel(trUtf8("Bal part"));

jobbfelulet=new QVBoxLayout();
jobbkozepfelulet=new QVBoxLayout();
balkozepfelulet=new QVBoxLayout();
balfelulet=new QVBoxLayout();
osszefogo=new QHBoxLayout();

jobbfelulet->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
jobbkozepfelulet->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
balfelulet->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
balkozepfelulet->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

balfelulet->addWidget(balcimke);
balkozepfelulet->addWidget(balkozepcimke);
jobbfelulet->addWidget(jobbcimke);
jobbkozepfelulet->addWidget(jobbkozepcimke);

osszefogo->addLayout(balfelulet);
osszefogo->addLayout(balkozepfelulet);
osszefogo->addLayout(jobbkozepfelulet);
osszefogo->addLayout(jobbfelulet);

setLayout(osszefogo);
```

How could I remove the space between them, or is there a better method to do this? I've created the labels for the layout size allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the documentation there's a `setSpacing(int x)` method for `QLayouts` that allows you to edit the spacing in between the elements, you may also need to add some `QSpacerItems` to get the positioning exactly where you want it, or apply constraints with the `setGeometry(QRect rect)` method.

Comment: QSpacerItems is what I exactly needed, now I don't have to put the QLabels into the layouts. (By the way setSpacing didn't work, but now I don't need labels anymore so it's ok). Thank you!

Comment: No problems, just in case anyone comes in the future `setSpacing` is a weird one that seems to work inconsistently depending on how you've setup your layout. Qt layouts are great but I've found often require some massaging to get what you want.